# Linear model theory online resources

Tags: regression, anova, generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, linear-model

I was wondering if you could tell me some online videos or other resources to learn theory of linear models. I am a visual learner. I learn more from video lectures. My focus is to learn:

Matrices, generalized inverses, projection matrices, multivariate distributions, conditional distributions, quadratic forms and their distributions, MLE and least square estimators, estimability and Gauss-Markov theorem, confidence intervals, general linear models, ANOVA and F-tests.

Thank you so much for your time.